Accessing PHP's enum's 'value' property statically
Suppose a PHP trait that looks like this;
trait Accessor
    {
        public static function int():int
        {
            return self::value;
        }
    }

and an enum to go with it;
enum Titular: int
    {
        use Accessor;

        case minimus=1;
        case maximus=2;
    }

What would the implementation be for the int() method to return the value of the current enum, like so?
Titular::minimus::int(); //1

Enum's 'value' property cannot be accessed statically like that: self::value. This I believe is well known. Trying to do so produces a fatal error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant Titular::value in .... Non-static properties cannot be accessed statically.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/CHnao
Am hoping for some implementation that would return the value through a static method.

Well, have you tried it? What happened?

@ADyson Well, calling $this->value is not legal in PHP inside a static method.

You haven't tried to use $this->value in your code, so how is that relevant? You said like so?...and gave some code. If you want to know if that works, try it. Have you tried it? What was the result? Provide a [mre] of the issue you experienced. There seem to be just 3 disparate, incomplete snippets of code here, rather than a worked example of what you're trying to do.

@ADyson Just updated the question with what I've tried. Kindly review.

Can you edit it into a coherent worked example which generates that error, as I mentioned already, rather than several disparate semi-complete snippets. That will be much clearer for future readers to understand the scenario you're talking about.

@ADyson You make a great point for future readers. Just did. However, there isn't much to be said about this enum problem because they don't exactly follow class rules. There is still alot of undocumented enum behaviors, this being one of them. Was hoping someone might have come across it.

I didn't get the point of your question. If you accepted an answer that using an instance method, why did you ask for a static method in the first place?

@shingo The accepted answer had to do with the fact that enums cannot be instantiated and therefore there is no way to statically get the value of the enum. The accepted answer shows that there is no way to get it other than to do it dynamically. Effectively am conceding to this fact.

The accepted answer shows that there is no way to get it other than to do it dynamically...does it? It shows you that removing static will work, but I'm not sure it proves there's no other way, or do much to explain why that is (the only brief, unattributed remark alludes to how static methods work, not to how enums work). So it's fine as an example of an alternative approach / workaround, but I personally wouldn't say it directly answers your question from a technical point of view.

enums cannot be instantiated and therefore there is no way to statically get the value...are you sure that's what you mean? Instantiation involves non-static things, normally. You have to instantiate a class in order to use any non-static methods, for example.

You don't need a Trait in order to get the enum's value - you can just write echo Titular::minimus->value; . Demo: https://3v4l.org/7TeMe . Was there a particular reason you wanted to use a Trait, or was it just one type of approach you tried? -> technically isn't static, but do you need it to be static? What's your actual objective here?

@ADyson yes, it doesn't answer conclusively, but what does? And no, removing the static keyword doesn't either. Please remember that enum cases are represented internally as constants on the enum itself. This is why you get a copy of the enum 'class' it was defined in whenever you reference them. For that reason, you cannot use  the new keyword to get an instance of the enum itself inside the static method.

@ADyson So far the only technique left is to use reflection to extract the value. But for that, you need the instance itself, which internally can only be obtained using $this keyword. Attempting to use static::class or self::class will result in a fatal error as mentioned above. The solution, therefore, is still in the wind. But since we cannot spend another 48 hours that we don't have looking for it, am begrudgingly reverting to this scenario for now. Yes, I encourage and expect more answers and will amend acceptations accordingly. For now, the man wins. Lets give him due credit.

@ADyson Sorry I also meant to answer your question. Yes, there is a big reason for the int method. Am chaining enums and using dot notation to get a value buried deep in the chain like such ::int('titular.anglicized.minimus'). As you know, PHP enums have no inheritance. The current enum value was meant to be a fallback.

Am chaining enums...how, exactly? And why? Would you be better with a multi-dimensional array, perhaps?

@ADyson The reason for the static method was preventing jacking the chain. Without it, as suggested in the answer, I'd have to do Titular::anglicized->int('minimus). But this is prone to error. These enums are a part of a large database composition.

It sounds like an overly-complex case of using the wrong tool for the job. But that's just my instinct / opinion. Obviously I can't see your full implementation and usage of the chaining, or the uses cases you're envisaging ("database composition" could mean a number of things).

use this
public function int(): int # remove static 
{
    return $this->value;
}

You can call
echo Titular::minimus->int(); # 1


Static methods belong to the class itself, not to any instance

